# A Nic and a USB wireless adapter, when one is on, the other stops working

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, usb, network-adapter

I have NIC and wireless USB adaptor.

Previously, both accessed separated networks and worked together.

The wired nic is connected to a piece of equipment. I have it on a submask of 255.0.0.0 with a static IP

The Wireless USB adapter is on a domain based network, on a different subnet, using DHCP.

Everytime I have both running together, the nic attached to the piece of equipment stops sending jobs. It still shows connected and I can still ping but the jobs are no longer sent...

As soon as the wireless is stopped, the jobs start showing up..

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a [subnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) mask of 255.0.0.0? A subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 allows you to assign IP addreses to 254 systems in the subnet, which is likely far more than you need, whereas a 255.0.0.0 subnet mask might be used if you needed to provide IP addresses for 16,777,214 hosts - see this [Internet Protocol (IPv4) Subnet Chart](https://www.pantz.org/software/tcpip/subnetchart.html). That might not be your problem if the one network interface uses addresses in the range 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255, which is [private IP address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network), aka RFC 1918 address space, and the other interface uses some other address range, but if you aren't using 10.x.x.x address space on the interface using that subnet mask and something else on the other interface, you may need to change your subnet mask. E.g., 255.255.255.0 would likely be adequate.

Answer (score 0):

Are both interfaces in the same subnet ?
Check your routes `route print`  and if needed add routes to your equipment via NIC